# Dojo/ASP.Net/Entity Framework - Bind data to Dojo DataGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datagrid, dojo, bind

I need to pull table data from EF/a database and bind to a Dojo DataGrid inide an ASP.Net MVC 3 app.  I guess I have to create a JS object/array from the data from a db/EF 1st, before it's bound, right?  Should I convert the data to a JSON object 1st?  Also the some grids would need to be hierarchical (ie certain cells may have repeating groups).  Is there any way to directly bind something like a .Net DataSet or a hierarchical JS object directly to the Jodo grid?  I guess I could traverse a host language construct like a .Net DS/EF object and create something to pass in, but also wondering a best practice on how to get the data from the host language construct to the grid on the client side, say, if I did an AJaX call to refresh the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could finde your answer in 
[Connecting Dojo DataGrid to Entity Framework 4.1 using JsonRest Store and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331920/Connecting-Dojo-DataGrid-to-Entity-Framework-4-1-u)